# how to get neteller payment status with curl?

Tags: php, curl, payment, neteller

***Hello!
i want to make a neteller payment method on my website.
is there a method to check when the payment failed , check if the customer entered an invalid account id or it's invalid secure id.
i really didn't find any solution in google about this problem.***

Comment: Please check amended link in which they have given the brief intro of api 
https://paysafegroup.github.io/neteller_rest_api_v1/#/introduction/technical-introduction/pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, the documentation is available on this link: https://paysafegroup.github.io/neteller_rest_api_v1/

I am guessing that you are integrating the deposit functionality, which is in section "Payments" >> "Request payment".

When you send your payment request to the API, you will always receive a response, which will either be a successful one (HTTP status code = 200), or you will get an error (HTTP status code = 4xx or 5xx).

You can see sample error responses in section "HTTP Responses". The error response will contain a unique code, indicating the reason for the transaction failure. You can then handle this code and if necessary show an error message to the user based on this.

Example error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "20008",
        "message": "Invalid verification code"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but is it easy to get a neteller api tokens? cause when I requested it , they didnt agree on giving me :/